# File.open in block form sometimes raises IOError: closed stream

Tags: ruby

I have an object that is able to store its own `Marshal.dump` to disk. In reduced form:

```rb
class MyObject
  # while the rest of the class is removed for brevity, this is the actual
  # save method
  def save
    File.open("/some/path", "wb") { |f| f << Marshal.dump(self) }
  end
end
```

`.save` can be called repeatedly during the lifetime of the object instance. In manual tests this works fine - the current state overwrites the prior one on disk.

In production however, the above sometimes fails with `IOError: closed stream`, and the created file has a length of zero bytes.

From what I understand, `closed stream` is raised when trying to access an IO stream which has already been closed - so far, so sensible.

What I do not understand is how this may occur in the above case. From what I see, for every call to `#save` I

1. have `File.open` initialize a fresh IO stream
2. write to it
3. have it automatically closed when the block given to `File.open` returns

Where or how in the above scenario might the IO stream become closed prematurely?

Comment: Is it possible something else is trying to access that same file at the same time?

Comment: Parallel access is unlikely, but possible. But would that explain an `IOError: closed stream`? In case of some kind of collision between A and B, I would expect either B to overwrite A, or the `File.open` of B to fail.

Comment: I just tried this - if you open two IO streams to the same file in parallel, closing the first does not affect the second. Writing to the second stream after the first was closed overwrites the content of the first, but does not raise `closed stream`.

Comment: Maybe the error is caused by `Marshal.dump(self)` rather than by writing to the file.

Comment: @Stefan possibly. But marshalling unmarshallable objects raises TypeErrors. Where would the IOError stem from?

Comment: @janfoeh I don't know, but If you ruled out writing to `f` as the cause, there's little left beside `Marshal.dump` itself. I would start by separating the method calls inside `save` to get a less ambiguous backtrace, e.g. use `data = Marshal.dump` and `f << data` and put them on separate lines, then look which one causes the exception. If it's really `Marshal.dump` (that was merely a guess BTW), you can try dumping each of the object's instance variable in a loop to see which one causes the exception.

Comment: @Stefan you're right. I was hoping somebody might chime in with something blindingly obvious I've overlooked, but that does not seem to be the case. I'll instrument the class up the wazoo to get better insights. Getting this deployed will take a few days, but I'll report back as soon as I have anything.

Comment: @janfoeh debugging such occasional problems in production can be really tedious  Looking forward to your findings!

Comment: @Stefan your guess was correct - I do have an issue with undumpable state that crept in somewhere. All my ivars are inconspicuous; some of them are Hashes though, so the culprit is likely hiding in some Hash value. I will probably end up following your advice and attempt to serialize everything one-by-one when the error occurs, then dump the offending value as JSON. Thanks for your time and input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your MyObject instance holding onto a closed stream in an instance variable?  According to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Marshal.html#method-c-dump), Marshal can't dump objects related to the system like `File`.  So `Marshal.dump` could be throwing the error depending upon what MyObject is holding onto:

```rb
class MyObject
  def initialize(value = nil)
    @some_attribute = value
  end

  def dump
    Marshal.dump(self)
  end
end

# Works OK with string value in attribute
obj = MyObject.new('abc')
 => #<MyObject:0x00007f961766ae18 @some_attribute="abc">
obj.dump
 => "\x04\bo:\rMyObject\x06:\x14@some_attributeI\"\babc\x06:\x06ET"

# Fails with open File
file = File.open('Test')
obj = MyObject.new(file)
 => #<MyObject:0x00007f9619ca34e0 @some_attribute=#<File:Test>>
obj.dump
# (irb):47:in `dump': can't dump File (TypeError)

# Fails with closed File
file.close
obj = MyObject.new(file)
 => #<MyObject:0x00007f9611d3d7c8 @some_attribute=#<File:Test (closed)>>
obj.dump
# (irb):47:in `internal_encoding': closed stream (IOError)
```

Maybe you'll need to explicitly write out how you want to serialize your object to avoid this.

Comment: Trying to marshall an unmarshallable object would raise a TypeError, not an IOError, wouldn't it? The save function works as described - it uses File.open with a block and retains no IO references I'm afraid.

Comment: The examples above show that it can give different kinds of errors including `TypeError` and `IOError`.  You can test it out by pasting the above code into an IRB console.  If your instance of MyObject is holding onto complex IO objects somewhere in its instance variables then calling `Marshal.dump(self)` could throw an `IOError`.

Comment: The object in question contains deserialized JSON responses - for it to somehow gain a different IO reference unrelated to the save-to-disk functionality, something _really_ funky would be required. But since I do not have any better ideas, I'll instrument the code to dump the classes of all ivars when the exception is raised. Getting this deployed will take a few days, but I'll report back then.

Comment: Regarding your comment that `Marshal.dump` shouldn't be raising an `IOError` like this--I now see that was reported as a [Ruby bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18077) and was fixed [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4758).  It looks like that fix got into the Ruby 3.1 release and hasn't been pushed backward.  The bug still exists in 3.0.6.  So if you're on 3.1 or later then this might not be the issue.

Comment: Interesting find, thank you! I've just deployed a change that splits the save functionality over multiple lines, as per @stefan s suggestion and logs stack traces as well as the classes of the object ivars. Hopefully I'll know more come Monday morning.

Comment: I have my first caught exception now, and the IOError does indeed occur during `Marshal.dump` - specifically during a call to `internal_encoding`. No idea whos `internal_encoding` it is, though. Dumping the class names of all objects I return in `#marshal_dump` did not help either, because the culprit probably hides in some Hash value. Anyway, you were right - I have an issue with undumpable state. Thank you!